# Differentiation of a circle

Tags: derivatives, circles

As a discus thrower is spinning counterclockwise to throw a discus, the discus travels along the path given by the circle $x^2+y^2=4$. If the discus is released at the point $(\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$ and travels along a path tangent to the circle at the point of release for a total of $200$ feet, where does the discus land? Give the $(x,y)$-coordinates.

I have no idea where to begin! :(

Comment: The initial position the discus is in at the moment it takes off is somewhere along the circle, denoted by the path $x^2+y^2=4$. At the time of its release, that discus travels at a straight line, tangent to the circle. What's the line tangent to (√2, √2)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Calculus is actually unnecessary to solve this question. [If you must, then use implicit differentiation to find the slope of the tangent line at the given point.] Here's an outline to solve the problem via pre-calculus knowledge:

- Find the slope $m_r$ of the radius connecting the center to the point of tangency.
- Since radii are perpendicular to tangents in a circle, the slope of the tangent line is $m$, the negative reciprocal of $m_r$.
- Using the slope-point formula, the equation of the tangent line is:
  $$
  y - \sqrt 2 = m(x - \sqrt 2) \tag 1
  $$
- Recall that the equation for the circle centred at the point of tangency with radius $200$ is given by:
  $$
  (x - \sqrt 2)^2 + (y - \sqrt 2)^2 = 200^2 \tag 2
  $$
- Solve the system of equations consisting of $(1)$ and $(2)$. You will get two intersection points; be sure to use the point that is in the counterclockwise direction.